# Connexion a un servidor via ssh

Tags: bash, shell

Quiero saber cómo puedo conectarme un servidor vía `SSH` metiendo todo los datos (*user*, *host*, *password*) en un `script .sh`,

Necesito que este `script .sh` se ejecuté de manera automática mediante un `cron` y que este acceda a una base de datos en el servidor
.
Tengo el siguiente código pero no sé cómo meterle mano

```
#!/bin/bash 
HOST="aqui_pon_la_maquina_remota" 
USER="aqui_pon_el_usuario_remoto" 
PASS="aqui_pon_el_password_remoto" 
CMD=$@ 
VAR=$(expect -c " 
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$HOST $CMD 
match_max 100000 
expect \"*?assword:*\" 
send -- \"$PASS\r\" 
send -- \"\r\" 
expect eof 
") 
echo "===============" 
echo "$VAR"
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres a conectarte a un servidor por medio de un script? ¿Por qué protocolo? ¿FTP, SSH, SFTP?

Comment: Por el protocolo ssh

Comment: ¿Cual es el la finalidad de hacerlo mediante un script? Si su sintaxis es bastante simple: `ssh user@host`

Comment: Necesito ejecutar un script de manera automática (cron) que accede a una base de datos en el servido .

Comment: Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir tu comentario y ser un poco más específico para poder ayudarte con tu problema, también puedes agregar un poco de código (si es que lo haz intentado) de lo que llevas para solucionar tu problema

Comment: En el mundo laboral para evitar problemas cuando se cambien las contraseñas, se suele utilizar los certificados de confianza y así tienes mayor seguridad que al dejarla en un archivo que puede ser utilizado para vulnerar el sistema

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te valió, por favor, marcala como valida. Si no te valió ninguna comentalo para buscar alternativas que te puedan valer.

Answer (score 1):

Partiendo de lo que nos cuentas vamos a empezar por cerciorarnos de que el comando `expect` esté instalado, así que en consola ejecutarás un:

`sudo apt-get -y install expect`

El cual te va a devolver algo como esto si ya lo tienes instalado:

> Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
>   Creando árbol de dependencias
>   Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
>   expect ya está en su versión más reciente (5.45-7).
>   0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.

Si no lo tienes instalado simplemente te lo va a instalar, ahora bien, vas a cambiar tu `script` por esto:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh user@host "ls -l ~;" # Entre comillas van tus comandos, para ejecutar varios simplemente puedes separarlos con un *punto y coma ;*
expect "password:"
send "YOUR_PASSWORD\r"
interact
```

Luego, para ejecutarlo, no vamos a hacerlo como con cualquier otro `.sh` archivo mediante un `sh script.sh` si no que lo ejecutaremos de la siguiente manera:

```
/usr/bin/expect script.sh
```

Y voilá, la consola te entregará algo como esto (dependiendo de los comandos que le envíes, obviamente):

> spawn ssh user@host ls -l ~;
>   user@host's password:
>   total 4
>   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May 19  2016 tmp

**Nota:** el prompt de `user@host's password:` igual te va a aparecer pero no deberás escribir nada, solo esperar a que el `interact` se ejecuté

Answer (score 1):

Si en algún momento esa contraseña cambia, el script deja de tener sentido.

Creo que en este caso y dado que es un `cron` lo mejor que puedes hacer es copiar la clave `ssh` y luego configurar tu `ssh` para que se conecte automáticamente.

Copiar ssh: `ssh-copy-id root@host`

Y luego en `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host nombreServidor
Hostname host
User root
Port 22
```

Te pongo un ejemplo, si me quisiera conectar a un ordenador de mi red local llamado `serverPruebas` con la IP `192.168.1.2`

```
Host servidorPruebas
Hostname 192.168.1.2
User root
Port 22
```

De esta manera solamente con escribir `ssh servidorPruebas` el sistema se conecta sin necesidad de contraseña.

Y si alguna vez cambia la contraseña, no tengo que preocuparme, porque me conecto mediante la `ssh key`.